# Autohide Grid Row in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I am trying to build a full screen app that will have rows/columns in the grid rows.
What i want is the corner rows/columns to be collapsed by default and whenever the cursor is at the edge the row/column should be uncollapsed that is it would become visible(something like the media players in windows do with he play controls.

Can somebody help me with the details about what to do to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set the row you want to hide height to 0 and add MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. Name your row (so you can call it) and then modify the height in MouseEnter method (increase so it is visible) and MouseLeave method (decrease back to 0 to hide).

I haven't got access to VS at the moment so I am not 100% sure they are the event names, but should give you the gist of what I mean.

Comment: Ok that did it but i had to sen the events of the control in the row rather than of the row. but i set the size of the row.

Comment: Now any idea how to set animate the process. I am able to animate if i set the height of the control to 0 instead of the row.